When a system of polynomial equations have a unique solution?
I am trying to find simple conditions on when a system of $m$ polynomial equations in $n$ variables for $m > n$ has a unique solution.
Specifically, let $f_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ be  multivariate polynomials of degree at most $d$, and let $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$. We now form the following system of equations:
$$ \forall i\in\{1,\dots,m\}, \quad f_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) - f_i(a_1,\dots,a_n) = 0$$
We know that this system has at least one solution. When does this system has a unique solution?
Another (perhaps easier) setting to prove is when we have a single polynomial $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and create $m$ polynomials by randomly sampling the coefficients of $f$. Namely, for each $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ sample all the coefficients of $f$ i.i.d from some distribution (e.g. standard Gaussian or uniform on some bounded interval) and form the system of equations again as above.
If the degree is $1$ then we have a system of linear equations, which is easy. Also, sampling random coefficients would almost surely provide a unique solution. I also tried to use Bézout's theorem, however, it only works for the case of $m=n$ and only provides an upper bound which seems rather non-tight for this case.

The intuition I have for the random polynomial is that if we sample n polynomials at random, then the probability they will have a common solution at $\infty$ is 0. Then, we can use Bézout's theorem to get that there are only finitely many solutions. If we add another random polynomial of the above form, the probability that one of the solutions that is not  x_1=a_1,...,x_n=a_n will also solve this polynomial will also be 0. Thus, we will get a unique solution. However, I'm not sure how to formalize the probability statements about the random polynomials.
